# Как вывести ярлык названия произвольного поля?

Tags: wordpress

Использую ACF, создал группу полей, вывожу все данные произвольных полях поста

```
var_dump(get_post_meta(88))
```

выдает такой массив:

```
array(22) {
  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1519921388:1"
  }
  ["protective_packing"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(580) "text 1"
  }
  ["_protective_packing"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "field_5a97345fa9e31"
  }      
  ["free_storage"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(580) "text 2"
  }
  ["_free_storage"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "field_5a973b9d5dabb"
  }
```

В данном выводе можно получить имя поля ["protective_packing"], например, а как получить ярлык поля, который называется "Защитная упаковка"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функции ACF.

```
$field = get_field_object( 'protective_packing' );
```

Функция вернет массив такого вида:

```
array(
    'ID'                => 0,
    'key'               => '',
    'label'             => '',
    'name'              => '',
    'prefix'            => '',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'value'             => null,
    'menu_order'        => 0,
    'instructions'      => '',
    'required'          => 0,
    'id'                => '',
    'class'             => '',
    'conditional_logic' => 0,
    'parent'            => 0,
    'wrapper'           => array(
        'width'             => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'id'                => ''
    )
);
```

Насколько я помню, нужное вам имя будет в `$field['label']`.

Подробнее в [документации](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/).

**Update**

Вот вывод этой функции в отладчике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я пробовал эту функцию, но она НЕ выводит ЯРЛЫК произвольного поля....ярлык храниться в таблице wp_postmeta  и имеет такой вот вид:

Comment: a:13:{s:3:"key";s:19:"field_5a97345fa9e31";s:5:"label";s:70:"Пломбировка и защитная упаковка груза";s:4:"name";s:18:"protective_packing";s:4:"type";s:8:"textarea";s:12:"instructions";s:0:"";s:8:"required";s:1:"0";s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:11:"placeholder";s:0:"";s:9:"maxlength";s:0:"";s:4:"rows";s:0:"";s:10:"formatting";s:2:"br";s:17:"conditional_logic";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:1:"0";s:5:"rules";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"field";s:4:"null";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}}s:8:"allorany";s:3:"all";}s:8:"order_no";i:0;}

Comment: может подскажете как его распарсить?

Comment: Ну как это она не выводит, когда выводит? Смотрите, проверил в отладчике: http://take.ms/SHid4